# Baking two procedural materials

Tags: uv, shaders, baking, procedural

I ended up creating an eyeball from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcHX4AT1vtg), but I don't know how to bake these two materials into one image. Only one material is baked. Tell me how to solve this problem, please

Eyeball
[image]

---

Answer for user Geri. This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://youtu.be/9airvjDaVh4

This will work with procedural materials, and eevee as well. You only need cycles for the baking part.

But basically, you need to put the image texture node you want to bake to - that's also selected - in the other materials.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but the stitches remained, and the cornea turned out to be black. I will send the image with the following comment.

Comment: Sorry, I know what to do next: I will remove the seams with a _soften brush_ and then add _roughness map_

Comment: After fiddling around for an hour or so, I couldn't figure out how to make the iris part of the outer mesh transparent with image textures. Baked out a transmission map, applied all the correct material settings, but it still opaque. I suggest making a new question about it.

Comment: okay, thanks for trying to help me!